# Python PyGTK ListView sorting

Tags: python, listview, sorting, pygtk

I got a problem with listviews, using PyGTK. Here is the situation:

Let's assume we got a listview, containing a playlist with two rows: Song name and artist:

```
Song 1, Artist C
Song 2, Artist A
Song 3, Artist B
```

(In reality, there a some more columns)

Every row can be used to sort the view. Sorting by artist, would lead to the following result:

```
Song 2, Artist A
Song 3, Artist B
Song 1, Artist C
```

What I need now, is the current order of the playlist. Assuming the player plays Song 3 (Artist B), the Song ends, but the user changed the order by sorting by artist. The next song on the playlist is now Song 1.

The gtk.ListStore still contains the old order, which means, the player will stop after Song 3, because the playlist ended here before the reordering.

I do not need the path of the song in the List- or Treeview, as Song 1 will always have (0,). What I need is the CURRENT order of the list in the view.

I tried a lot, but did not found a solution. If required, I can add the code.

Update:

I add some code to clarify:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):

    "Window stuff.."

    self.treeView = gtk.TreeView(self.create_model())
    self.treeView.set_rules_hint(True)
    select = self.treeView.get_selection()
    select.connect("changed", self.on_tree_selection_changed)
    self.treeView.connect("button-press-event", self.on_double_click)


    "Window stuff.. Packing etc."


def create_model(self):
    """Returns a gtk.ListStore"""
    store = gtk.ListStore(str, str, str, str, int)
    for song in self.songs:
        store.append([song.track, song.title, song.artist, song.get_length(), song.id])
    return store


def create_columns(self, treeView):

    rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Track", rendererText, text=0)
    column.set_sort_column_id(0)
    treeView.append_column(column)

    rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Title", rendererText, text=1)
    column.set_sort_column_id(1)    
    treeView.append_column(column)

    rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Artist", rendererText, text=2)
    column.set_sort_column_id(2)    
    treeView.append_column(column)

    rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Length", rendererText, text=3)
    column.set_sort_column_id(3)    
    treeView.append_column(column)

    rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
    column = gtk.TreeViewColumn("Id", rendererText, text=4)
    column.set_sort_column_id(4)
```

Comment: adding some code will help

Comment: have a look here http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreesortable.html

Comment: I added the related code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply hat to use TreeModelSort(childmodel)

Thank you all for your help!

The solution:

```
self.sorted_model = gtk.TreeModelSort(self.list_store())

def get_current_order(self):
    current_order = []
    widget = self.sorted_model
    for item in widget:
        current_order.append(item[5])
    return current_order
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your format of the songs in this order

```
from operator import itemgetter

list1=[('Song 1', 'Artist C'),('Song 2', 'Artist A'),('Song 3', 'Artist B')]

#sort by artist
print sorted(list1,key=itemgetter(1))

#output [('Song 2', 'Artist A'), ('Song 3', 'Artist B'), ('Song 1', 'Artist C')]
#sort by song
print sorted(list1,key=itemgetter(0))
#[('Song 1', 'Artist C'), ('Song 2', 'Artist A'), ('Song 3', 'Artist B')]
```

Comment: There are builtin methods in pygtk to do this.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i donot know abt that.So should i delete answer?

Comment: well an alternative would to add them ;)

Comment: @user3804367 he has provided a link in your question . check that

Comment: Thanks, I missed the link. I will check both suggestions asap. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Uhm.. I think, this answer does not really fit.. I need a way to get the list from the view. So, the problem is not to sort it or something.